# Curl client in linux don't reply SYN/ACK frame in setting up a TCP three handshake

Tags: curl, tcp, handshake

Situation : In my project, i have 2 host h1 and h2, between them having a switch s1. I want when h1 uses cURL tool sending a SYN frame to h2 to establish a three handshake, but before h2 receive this SYN frame, s1 will capture it and send back to h1 a fake SYN/ACK frame with ethernet address, ip address and tcp port of h2.

Problem: I haved captured SYN/ACK of both s1 by wireshark and they are all the same in ethernet, ip, tcp header but cURL in h1 don't reply SYN/ACK of s1. I don't understand why this happened.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you try disabling TCP timestamps? ('sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0')

Comment: @AliÖzgürArgunşah i have tried, but it don't work. I think curl has a mechanism to detect spoofed packets.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in checksum field in SYN/ACK frame. Thanks for everyone's help.